# How to write string array to a HDF5 dataset with Fortran API?

Tags: fortran, hdf5

A string array is defined using fortran language:

```
character(len = 20), dimension(5) :: strings = (/"hello", "world", "Hello", "HDF5", "fortran"/)
```

Now I want to save this array into a dataset using `h5ltmake_dataset_string_f()` interface illustrated by HDF5 API reference documentation

> **Fortran90 Interface:** h5ltmake_dataset_string_f
>
> subroutine h5ltmake_dataset_string_f(loc_id,dset_name,buf,errcode )
>
> ```
>     implicit none
> ```
>
> integer(HID_T), intent(IN) :: loc_id           ***! file or group identifier***
>
> character(LEN=*), intent(IN) :: dset_name      ***! name of the dataset***
>
> character(LEN=*), intent(IN), dimension(:) :: buf  ! data buffer
>
> integer :: errcode                             ***! error code***
>
> end subroutine h5ltmake_dataset_string_f

My calling code below

```
h5ltmake_dataset_string_f(group_id, dset_name, strings, error)
```

and group_id, dset_name and error have been defined before subroutine call.

But when I compile and build this code, compile error occurs says

> h5ltmake_dataset_string_f(): the actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated!

So how to write the strings into one dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use API [**h5dwrite_f(...)**](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Write), not h5ltmake_dataset_f() to write string array.

Answer (score 0):

Although the issue was opened several years ago, here goes a solution to write an array of strings ("hello", "world", "Hello", "HDF5", "fortran") into an HDF5 dataset in Fortran using HDFql (http://www.hdfql.com). Posting this in case others find themselves struggling with HDF5 low-level details when performing this type of operation:

```fortran
PROGRAM Example

    ! use HDFql module (make sure it can be found by the Fortran compiler)
    USE HDFql

    ! declare variables
    CHARACTER(LEN = 20), DIMENSION(5) :: strings = [CHARACTER(LEN = 20) :: "hello", "world", "Hello", "HDF5", "fortran"]
    CHARACTER :: variable_number
    INTEGER :: state

    ! create an HDF file named "example.h5" and use (i.e. open) it
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE AND USE FILE example.h5")

    ! create a dataset named "my_dataset" of type char (size 20) of one dimension (size 5)
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE DATASET my_dataset AS CHAR(5, 20)");

    ! register variable "strings" for subsequent use (by HDFql)
    state = hdfql_variable_transient_register(strings)
    WRITE(variable_number, "(I0)") state

    ! insert (i.e. write) content of variable "strings" into dataset "my_dataset"
    state = hdfql_execute("INSERT INTO my_dataset VALUES FROM MEMORY " // variable_number)

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: The fortran API for HDFql is currently not supported on Windows though, right?

Comment: @mikeck: as of version 2.0.0, HDFql supports Fortran in Windows through its Intel Fortran Compiler (IFORT) wrapper.